# How to override/replace @MockBean field declared in the parent class with @Autowired real bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, integration-testing, spring-test

To avoid the Spring context reloading again and again, I have moved `@MockBean` annotated injection to a parent class, something like this.

```
@SpringBootTest
.......
public abstract  BaseTest {
    @MockBean
    protected OneService oneService;
```

This serves the test classes which need a mock for `OneService`. However, for the test that I would like also extended from `BaseTest`, but inject the real `OneService` via `@Autowired` will not work, as it will inherit the mock injection from the `BaseTest`.

```
public AnotherTest extends BaseTest {
    @Autowired
    protected OneService oneService;
```

Even I used `@Autowired` annotation, the `oneService` field will be the mock instance inherited from `BaseTest`.

Is there a way I can force inject to use autowired?

Comment: Based on a quick glance of the Spring Boot Test internals, I don't think it's possible to achieve that currently. The `DefinitionsParser` appears not to take into account that a field may be overridden by a subclass: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/DefinitionsParser.java

Comment: Try constructor injection that way might be possible to supply the bean from child to parent have a look at that approach, might help.

Comment: thanks. is there an alternative I am trying to do? I was thinking to use @ Qualifier, but it means I need to initialize the bean as a mock and actual OneService with a qualifier respectively. I am struggling to get it to work. I might miss understanding somewhere. The @ MockBean inject automatically to context, so I can do nothing, so I can only update the OneService implmentation with qualifier and change all places using it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java there is technically no way to override a field. When you declare a field with the same name in a subclass, that field shadows the field with the same name in the superclass. So that is one hurdle.

The second hurdle stems from the fact that there is no way in Spring Boot's testing support to turn off mocking of a bean in a subclass if the superclass configures the mocking via `@MockBean`.

Thus, the solution is to invert what you are trying to do by having the real bean injected via `@Autowired` in the superclass and then turn on mocking for the specific bean type in the subclass.

1. Declare the `@Autowired` field in the superclass but do not redeclare the field in the subclass.
2. Declare `@MockBean` at the class level in the subclass, specifying which classes (i.e., bean types) to be mocked.

That last step results in the inherited field being injected with a mock in the subclass.

The following two classes demonstrate this technique in practice.

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = BaseTests.Config.class)
class BaseTests {

    @Autowired
    protected Service service;

    @Test
    void service() {
        assertThat(service.getMessage()).isEqualTo("real");
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        Service service() {
            return new Service();
        }
    }

    static class Service {
        String getMessage() {
            return "real";
        }
    }

}
```

```java
@MockBean(classes = BaseTests.Service.class)
class MockBeanTests extends BaseTests {

    @BeforeEach
    void setUpMock() {
        when(service.getMessage()).thenReturn("mock");
    }

    @Test
    @Override
    void service() {
        assertThat(service.getMessage()).isEqualTo("mock");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam for the great explanation. This really helps